# Fixing Keyboard shortcut send in Auto Hot Key

Tags: autohotkey

Hi this is a super easy question but I was hoping someone could help me solve two AutoHotKey questions.

I am trying to get the keys Cntrl, J and I to be a keyboard shortcut that sends alt,h,v, and f.

Thus far I have tried these two ways of typing it

```
^&j&i::Send, !&h&v&f

^ji::Send, !hvf
```

as well as each of those without the comma after send.

I am also looking to send these keys on a very small delay, such as 5ms between each key

I was thinking of using something like this

```
^&j&i::

{
Send, {! down}
sleep 5
Send, {h down}
sleep 5
Send, {v down}
sleep 5
Send< {f down}
}
```

but of course, that is not working either. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo
*Combinations of three or more keys are not supported.* With this in mind we need to check the key state of the control key before defining the hotkey.

A few other things to note: `SendInput` is the ideal send method, and you likely want those keys back into an up state which I've included in my example.

```
#if GetKeyState("LControl", "P")
{
    j & i::
    {
        SendInput {Alt down}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {h down}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {v down}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {f down}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {Alt Up}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {h Up}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {v Up}
        sleep 5
        SendInput {f Up}
        return
    }
}
```